# Okhttp3 is not see WebSocket interface in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, square, okhttp

I get some problems with okhttp3 lib.

I added the following line in my gradle file dependency:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

After that, I try to create webSocket connection like [okhttp websocket example](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/WebSocketEcho.java), but in Android Studio I don't see any classes and interfaces like

```
import okhttp3.WebSocket;
import okhttp3.WebSocketListener;
```

But I know that these files exist in okhttp3. Can anybody explain what I did wrong?

If we see in okhttp javadoc we can not find these classes. But they are in github.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add the `okhttp-ws` module.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
```

WebSockets are moving out of a separate, experimental artifact and into the core `okhttp` artifact for the next release, 3.5.0, which is what you see if you look at GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

Oct2019:

I have tried below line/version and works for me:

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.1")
```

reference:
https://github.com/square/okhttp